# Laravel 5.2 Get the most found record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## What I want to achieve

- Retrieve most found record in my database table called 'ratings' which contains the film_id and the rate it has

## What I have

So, I have a table called

> ratings
>   which has the following columns:
>   [image: Table Columns]

I also have to models:

- Film
- Rate

So the

> Rate
>   model is connected to the ratings table (which is the printscreen shown above)

## Results I want

I want to obtain the film which has most ratings, which the avg ratings of that film needs to be above 2.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's of the "gimme hte codez" variety. Please show us what you've tried, and we'll be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

For Highest Rate Movie:

In controller : ||first get the highest rate then use where to find

```
 $max =  DB::table('ratings')->max('rate');
 $rate = Rate::where('rate','=', $max)->first();
```

In view: || If you crate relation between two table

```
$rate->flim->name/id/anything;
```

here, $rate is the object which you pass form controller, 'flim' is the eloquent relation, and others is your database field...